# Documentation of Azure DevOps Server 2019 Rest API

Tags: azure-devops

Is there anywhere a documentation, that ony references the RestApi 5.0?
So I can find only what I am able to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can not choose versions on the start page of REST API but you can do that on any other page that describes calls (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):

[image]